# Syntax error in SQL code being used in R, no row_number function found

Tags: sql, r, dbi, dbplyr, rsqlite

I am using `RSQLite`, `DBI`, and `dbplyr` packages. I'm watching [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/Ww71knvhQ-s?t=486) by TechTFQ.

```
library(dbplyr)
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)

mtcars <- tibble::as_tibble(mtcars, rownames = 'car')  
sql_mtcars <- mtcars

con <- RSQLite::dbConnect(SQLite(), ":memory:")
dplyr::copy_to(con, sql_mtcars)

sql_mtcars_db <- tbl(con, "sql_mtcars")

sql_mtcars_db %>%
  dplyr::select(car, mpg, wt) %>%
  dplyr::show_query()

dbListTables(con)
```

I'm getting a syntax error with this line.

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, '
SELECT *
  row_number() over(partition by cyl) AS rn
FROM sql_mtcars 
  ')
```

> Error: near "row_number": syntax error

I'm certain that the SQL syntax I'm writing here is the same as what I'm watching in the YouTube video, except for the differences in the dataframe that I'm using and the variables that I'm calling.

What is the error that I'm running into? Is it the case that the dbplyr SQL doesn't have the full range of SQL verbs, or is it using a different SQL syntax?

I'm not even sure how to find a a key for the SQL syntax to use in this method. Asking for help through `?DBI`, `?dbplyr` or `?RSQLite` is not much help because there doesn't seem to be much in the way of documentation about the SQL verbs, and I haven't found a very comprehensive vignette to study.

Comment: Can you try with the github version of `RSQLite` as window functions are new in Sqlite

Comment: Ok I'm trying to install this: devtools::install_github("r-dbi/RSQLite") RStudio is stuck on that line of code for five minutes now

Comment: Error: Failed to install 'RSQLite' from GitHub:
  lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/cli/R/cli.rdb' is corrupt

Comment: I had similar issue in installing the github version.  Thanks for trying

Comment: ah ok I thought it was just on my end. Was about to restart computer to see

Comment: The CRAN version of RSQLite 2.2.12 has SQLite 3.82.2 and that has row_number.  This works for me on R version 4.1.3 Patched (2022-03-10 r81883) "Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)"  `library(sqldf); packageVersion("RSQLite");
sqldf("select sqlite_version()");
sqldf("SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by cyl) AS rn
  FROM mtcars")`

>

Comment: I tried your suggested code and it seemed to work! I'm not sure what it means that this version works: 
sqldf("SELECT mpg, wt, 
      row_number() over (partition by cyl) AS rn   
      FROM mtcars")

Comment: and this version doesn't work:
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, '
SELECT mpg, wt,
row_number() over (partition by cyl) AS rn   
FROM mtcars
  ')

Comment: Except maybe the sql involved with dbGetQuery doesn't have window functions and the sql with sqldf does?

Comment: sqldf uses RSQLite so if you use sqldf or RSQLite directly it should work.  Maybe there is a problem somewhere else.  Run the same sqldf command as in my last comment but add the `verbose=TRUE` argument and sqldf will display what RSQLite commands it is running and then try those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a comma after the `*`. The following works as expected:

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, '
SELECT *,
  row_number() over(partition by cyl) AS rn
FROM sql_mtcars 
  ')
```

Note the addition of a comma after the `*` and before the `row_number`.